# Ffmpeg - converting webm movie to flv movie not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I need to convert **.webm** files to **.flv**.
I have used

```
'exec("ffmpeg -i 1.webm -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -crf   22 -threads 0 1.flv");'.
```

When i use the above code, the file is converting to **1.flv** with 0 bytes. No data is in 1.flv file.

Comment: So, does it convert correctly when you run this in a command prompt or does it fail there too?

Comment: Please don't use every tag that you can think of and put it on the question. I removed a bunch of unrelated tags.